# Discuss Convergence of Series $n (e^{-1/n^2} - \cos^2{(\frac{1}{n}})) $

Tags: convergence-divergence, divergent-series

I presume this series converges to 0, how do I prove it?

$$\require{cancel} n (e^{-1/n^2} - \cos^2{(\frac{1}{n}}))
$$
If I do as @Alex suggested i get
\begin{align*}
\sim &n(1-\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{2n^4} -(1-\frac{1}{2n^2})^2)\\
&=n(\cancel{1}-\cancel{\frac{1}{n^2}}+\frac{1}{2n^4}-\cancel{1}+\cancel{\frac{1}{n^2}}-\frac{1}{4n^4})\\
&=\frac{n}{4}(\frac{2}{n^4}-\frac{1}{n^4}) = \frac{1}{4n^3}\stackrel{\infty}\to0
\end{align*}

Comment: what are you allowed to use?

Comment: All the criteria for series convergence, the convergence of the associated limit and also Taylor

Comment: And no technique from this collection worked when you tried it?

Comment: What do you mean? Is it $\sum n(e^{-1/n^2}-\cos^2(\frac{1}{n})^2)$?

Comment: What you did in the "If I do as ..." part is fine, but what is the last limit for? All you need is that your sequence behaves as $\;\frac1{4n^3}\;$ and this last one converges.

Comment: @Joanpemo The equivalent $1/(4n^3)$ is actually wrong.

Comment: @Did Thank you. Yes, I think it should be equivalent to $\;\frac5{6n^3}\;$ though it doesn't really affects the convergence, What I actually meant is why did Ludovico remarked that $\;\frac1{4n^3}\to0\;$ if what we need is to know whether the series of this last sequence converges or not.

Answer (score 2):

Expand $e^{-\frac{1}{n^2}} \sim 1- \frac{1}{n^2} + \frac{1}{2n^4}$ and $\cos \frac{1}{n} \sim 1-\frac{1}{2n^2}$.

Comment: This cannot work: indeed one must expand the exponential up to the $1/n^4$ term... *and likewise for the cosine*.

Comment: hmm, I didn't expand an further because I saw that 1's cancel out and the remaining terms are at least $O(\frac{1}{n^4})$ after squaring

Comment: OK, then you might want to cancel the $1/n^4$ term in the exponential.

Comment: 'cancel the term in the exponential' I'm not sure I'm following you: I get $\frac{1}{2n^4}$ from the exponential term and $-\frac{1}{4n^4}$ from the cosine (after squaring)

Comment: I am pointing at 1. the dissymetry of the expansions you are suggesting are necessary to solve this, and 2. the fact that the expansions $e^{-1/n^2}=1-1/n^2+o(1/n^2)$ and $\cos(1/n)=1-1/(2n^2)+o(1/n^2)$ suffice. Hence the suggestion to omit the $1/n^4$ term in the expansion of the exponential.

Comment: $-\cos^2 \frac{1}{n} \sim - (1-\frac{1}{2n^2})^2 = -1 + \frac{1}{2n^2} - \frac{1}{4n^4}$ so the first two terms cancel out. I don't understand what 'dissymmetry' you are talking about.

Comment: @Alex and Did take a look at my edit, I've done as Alex suggests and it should be ok

Comment: Last try: the $1/(2n^4)$ term in the expansion of the exponential is irrelevant, i.e. not useful to reach the conclusion. If one insists on mentioning it, then the $1/n^4$ term in the expansion of the cosine must appear as well. (By the way, the expansion in your last comment is wrong, even adding $o(1/n^4)$ everywhere, actually $-\cos^2(1/n)=-1/n^2+1/(3n^4)+o(1/n^4)$.)

Comment: ...And all this has the consequence (against which I am trying to warn from the start, but...) that the equivalent of $e^{-1/n^2}-\cos^2(1/n)$ computed in the OP's post following the indications in this answer, is **wrong**.

Comment: Are you saying that expanding terms up to different orders is a mistake?

Comment: How did you get that 3 in the denominator btw?

Comment: *Correction: $-\cos^2(1/n)=-1+1/n^2-1/(3n^4)+o(1/n^4)$.